# how to use unix configure to compile 32 bits executable on 64 bits

Tags: unix, configure

I want to compile a program using the standard ./configure , make, make install.
I am using 64 bits machine but I want the executable to be 32 bits executable.

What is the way to do this, I did ./configure --help but saw nothing on this (it has the --disable-64bit but it does not seem to do the work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the platform and compiler?

I'd be inclined to say either:

1. run configure to get your Makefile and then add then relevant compiler option to the CFLAGS macro, e.g. CFLAGS=${CFLAGS} -m32 for Sun cc, or
2. add that macro edit to the Makefile.in file being used as a template by configure.

---

#### Edit:

Forgot to add that I've done both several times before when I needed to.

Comment: @Aviator: -m32 is correct for SUNWspro (Sun C compiler) version 12; previous versions used other notations (like -xarch=sparcv9 or thereabouts).

Comment: @Rob: I often set CC="gcc -m32" or CC="gcc -m64" in the environment before running configure: `CC="gcc -m32" ./configure`

Comment: @Jonathan: Yeah.. thanks! I got it.. I was using -xarch stuff! :) Thats why got confused..

Comment: @Aviator, wait until you use SunStudio12.1. Oh, the chip and architecture options you will see.... to paraphrase Dr. Seuss (-:

Comment: @Rob: lol... Yeah.. Actually am fighting to get new one! :).. Its difficult to convince people here :).. Hope i will soon get latest ones!